# Database Object Mappings joining views

Tags: sql, database, oracle

For each of your tables (use user_tables), list its tablename, tablespace, creation date, number of
rows and average row length. (Note: creation date is in a different view-do not do a Cartesian
join!).

How do I pull the creation date when it is in a different view? here is what I have so far. everything is user_tables except created, it is in user_objects view.

SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLESPACE_NAME, CREATED, NUM_ROWS, AVG_ROW_LEN
FROM USER_TABLES;

Comment: Try looking at some examples of SQL joins, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Please beware that `NUM_ROWS` and `AVG_ROW_LEN` are not exact values. Instead they are from previously gathered statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Once you join `user_tables` and `user_objects` on a common column (that's table/object name), you get

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      t.table_name,
  3      t.tablespace_name,
  4      o.created,
  5      t.num_rows,
  6      t.avg_row_len
  7  FROM
  8           user_tables t
  9      JOIN user_objects o ON o.object_name = t.table_name
 10  WHERE
 11      ROWNUM <= 3;

TABLE_NAME      TABLESPACE_NAME CREATED               NUM_ROWS AVG_ROW_LEN
--------------- --------------- ------------------- ---------- -----------
GTT                             06.03.2022 08:35:00
SALESMAN        USERS           06.03.2022 08:43:40          2          26
STATES_TAB      USERS           07.03.2022 19:24:43          7          28

SQL>
```